BeginAccept not calling my function that calls EndAccept
I'm trying to get a console app running, where the server and client can message each other.
I had it working before, but it was with blocking or synchronous calls, like Send() or Receive(). I want to switch over to non-blocking calls because either the client or server has to wait to receive a message to send one and it isn't practical.
So, I started with BeginAccept() to get a feel of how they work, but my BeginAccept() isn't calling back to my AcceptCallback() that has the EndAccept() for a proper connection.
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class Server
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Set ipv4 address and socket to variables
        IPAddress ServerAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        int ServerPort = 1234;
        bool connected = false;

        //Setup the new socket with the parameters of addressFamily.interNetwork (tells it to use a ipv4 address)
        //socketType.stream and protocolType.tcp (tells it to have a connection tye of tcp)
        Socket ServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        ServerSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ServerAddress, ServerPort));

        //telling the socket to start listening and to only let 5 connections at one time
        ServerSocket.Listen(5);
        Console.WriteLine("Server is listening for connections");

        while (!connected)
        {
            ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), ServerSocket);
            
            if (ServerSocket.Connected == true)
            {
                connected = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");
            }
        }
        
        while (connected == true)
        {
            if (ServerSocket.Connected == true)
            {
                connected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                connected = false;
            }

            //setup a array called temp to store the clients data, set what you recieve from clientSocket to be put into an int called ClientBytes
            //convert the bytes from clientbytes to string to read it 
            byte[] temp = new byte[1024];
            int ClientBytes = ServerSocket.Receive(temp);

            if (ClientBytes <= 0 || temp == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                string ClientMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(temp, 0, ClientBytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved data from client: " + ClientMessage);
            }

            //Convert the message to bytes, store it in a array then send it down the client socket
            string ServerMessage = Console.ReadLine();
            if (ServerMessage == null || ServerMessage.Length == 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] temp2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ServerMessage);
                ServerSocket.Send(temp2);
            }

            /*ClientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            ClientSocket.Close();*/
        }

        if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.F10)
        {
            ServerSocket.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket ServerSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket Handler = ServerSocket.EndAccept(ar);
    }
}

I expected it to just connect, but it doesn't. I haven't tried much, to be honest, because I thought I had a good understanding of it, but I guess not.

Untested, but: try capturing the result of BeginAccept, and check .CompletedSynchronously / .IsCompleted - it might be that in this case, the async callback is not triggered if it executes synchronously

Why don't you just use normal async methods, rather than the old Begin End way?

@Charlieface I didn't realize that they were even a thing I tried implementing them the accept async worked but for the receive async it wont take in the temp to store the data "int ClientBytes = ServerSocket.ReceiveAsync(temp);" that line keeps giving me an error "the variable temp cannot be used with type arguments" any idea on how to fi this?

@MarcGravell How do i capture the result? when i do ServerSocket.CompletedSynchronously it doesn't show up on the list same as .IsCompleted

@Doblob83 var whatever = ServerSocket.BeginAccept(...) ?

You need to use await on functions marked Async that return a Task.

@MarcGravell when i got the result i did console.writeline to display it and it just put up a bunch of this "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToAsyncResult+TaskAsyncResult"

@Charlieface sorry but I'm new to unblocking where would i put the await anywhere i seemed to put it would give me a new error

int ClientBytes = await ServerSocket.ReceiveAsync(temp<byte>); but really you should use TcpClient like I show below

There is a lot wrong with your code:

BeginAccept etc is old-hat. Use the new Async functions with await.
Use TcpListener and TcpClient rather than raw sockets.
Don't bind to 127.0.0.1 unless you only want to listen to localhost requests (and then just use IPAddress.Loopback) otherwise just use IPAddress.Any.

public static async Task Main()
{
    int ServerPort = 1234;
    var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, ServerPort);
    listener.Start(5);
    Console.WriteLine("Server is listening for connections");

    while (true)
    {
        var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");
        // hand off client so we can carry on listening
        Task.Run(() => HandleClient(client));
    }
}    

public static async Task HandleClient(TcpClient client)
{
    using var _ = client;
    using var stream = client.GetStream();
    //setup a array called temp to store the clients data, set what you recieve from clientSocket to be put into an int called ClientBytes
    //convert the bytes from clientbytes to string to read it 
    byte[] temp = new byte[1024];
    do
    {
        int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(temp);
        if (bytesRead == 0)
            return;

        string ClientMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(temp, 0, ClientBytes);
        Console.WriteLine("Recieved data from client: " + ClientMessage);

        //Convert the message to bytes, store it in a array then send it down the client socket
        string ServerMessage = Console.ReadLine();
        if (ServerMessage is not { Length : > 0 })
            return;
    
        byte[] temp2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ServerMessage);
        await stream.WriteAsync(temp2);
    } while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.F10);  // how to end this loop??
}

Further notes:

You need some sort of message framing otherwise you have no guarantee as to how much data comes through on each read. TCP is a continuous stream, and any read/write may be broken up or joined together.
So you would read until you reach a message endpoint, parse what you have then loop back. Alternatively, each message can be prefixed with a length.
Encoding.ASCII is rather limiting.
Consider using some kind of CancellationTokenSource, perhaps combined with Console.CancelKeyPress, to shutdown the listener and sockets.


Your AcceptCallback() is likely being called, you are just not reporting anything from it.  Your main code is doing the logging, but it will never report a client has connected because it is looking for the wrong condition for that. You are running a busy loop that simply calls ServerSocket.BeginAccept() over and over endlessly, as ServerSocket.Connected will never be true - a listening TCP socket can never enter a Connected state, let alone perform read/send I/O.  Accepting a TCP client creates a new Socket that you must perform I/O on, but you are ignoring it.
As @Charlieface's answer describes, there are better ways to accomplish what you want.  But if you want to get your existing code working, then try restructuring it to something more like the following:
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Server
{
    private class ClientInfo
    {
        Socket clientSocket; 
        byte[] readBuffer;
        List<byte[]> sendBuffers;
        byte[] currSendBuffer;
        int sendTotal;
        int sentSoFar;

        public ClientInfo(Socket ClientSocket)
        {
            clientSocket = ClientSocket; 
            readBuffer = new byte[102];
            sendBuffers = new List<byte[]>();
            currSendBuffer = null;
            sendTotal = 0;
            sentSoFar = 0;
        }

        public void BeginReceive()
        {
            clientSocket.BeginReceive(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), this);
        }

        private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            int numRead = clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
            if (numRead > 0)
            {
                string ClientMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, numRead);
                Console.WriteLine("Received data from client: " + ClientMessage);
                BeginSendMsg("I GOT IT!");
                BeginReceive();
            }
            else
            {
                clientSocket.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected!");
            }
        }

        private BeginSendMsg(string Message)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Message);
            sendBuffers.Add(buffer);
            if (sendBuffers.Count == 1)
                BeginSendFirstBuffer();
        }

        private void BeginSendFirstBuffer()
        {
            currSendBuffer = sendBuffers[0];
            sendTotal = currSendBuffer.Length;
            sentSoFar = 0;
            BeginSendNextChunk();
        }

        private void BeginSendNextChunk()
        {
            clientSocket.BeginSend(currSendBuffer, sentSoFar, sendTotal - sentSoFar, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), this);
        }

        private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            int numSent = clientSocket.EndSend(ar);
            if (numSent <= 0)
            {
                clientSocket.Close();
                return;
            }
            sentSoFar += numSent;
            if (sentSoFar < sendTotal)
            {
                BeginSendNextChunk();
                return;
            }
            sendBuffers.RemoveAt(0);
            if (sendBuffers.Count == 0)
            {
                currSendBuffer = null;
                sendTotal = 0;
                sentSoFar = 0;
                return;
            }
            BeginSendFirstBuffer();
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        IPAddress ServerAddress = IPAddress.Loopback; // or IPAddress.Any
        int ServerPort = 1234;

        Socket ServerSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        ServerSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ServerAddress, ServerPort));
        ServerSocket.Listen(5);
        Console.WriteLine("Server is listening for connections");

        ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), ServerSocket);
            
        while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.F10) {}

        ServerSocket.Close();
    }

    private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket ServerSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket ClientSocket = ServerSocket.EndAccept(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");
        ClientInfo client = new ClientInfo(ClientSocket);
        client.BeginReceive();
        ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), ServerSocket);
    }
}


This looks like it should work thank you so much but it can seem to acsess any of the "private class ClientInfo
{
Socket socket;
byte[] readBuffer;
List<byte[]> sendBuffers;
byte[] currSendBuffer;
int sendTotal;
int sentSoFar;
    public ClientInfo(Socket ClientSocket)
    {
        socket = ClientSocket; 
        readBuffer = new byte[102];
        sendBuffers = new List<byte[]>();
        currSendBuffer = null;
        sendTotal = 0;
        sentSoFar = 0;
    }
}" protection level


@Doblob83 I updated my example.
